# How to manage development, production, testing configuraions with maven?

Tags: java, maven

I'm new to Maven and coming from a Rails background. At a high level, I want to connect to a different database if I'm running tests, running the app locally, and when I deploy to production.

Here's what I was thinking. When I run `mvn test` it should use test.properties, when I run `mvn jetty:run` locally it should use dev.properties, and when I deploy it should pickup a properties file that is already on the server, and not in the WAR.

But I have no idea how this is typically done in a Java project built with Maven.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your tests, you could put a test-only Spring config file or property file into the test resources of a module, and have that module generate a test-jar. Then reference that test-jar as a test scope dependency from any modules that need it during testing.

For running in dev mode vs. production mode, one possible non-Maven-related solution would be to make use of an environment variable that specifies a different Spring config/properties file/xml file to use.

Answer (score 6):

You can do that by using maven [profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html). You would set up a different profile for different environment, data set, etc and activate them based on the environment you are building against.

Answer (score 6):

We use profiles to distinguish between the different build phases, and we use the assembly plugin with different assembly descriptors for each profile. We have something like the code below. Our default profile is development, but when we release the "release" profile is activated automatically. The assembly descriptors are pretty simple and we have one "common" directory structure, one for development, and one for release.

```
  <build>
    <plugins>

      <!-- Enable Java 6 features. -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>6</source>
          <target>6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <!-- Configure for development environment. -->
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>package</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>assembly</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <descriptors>
            <descriptor>src/main/assembly/dist-dev.xml</descriptor>
          </descriptors>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <!-- Deployment configuration. -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
          <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
          <version>${project.version}</version>
          <packaging>zip</packaging>
          <file>target/${project.build.finalName}.zip</file>
          <url>${project.distributionManagement.snapshotRepository.url}</url>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <!-- Release configuration. -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <goals>assembly:assembly deploy:deploy-file</goals>
          <useReleaseProfile>false</useReleaseProfile>
          <arguments>-Prelease</arguments>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scm-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-bazaar</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>
  <profiles>

    <!-- Release profile. -->
    <profile>
      <id>release</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>

          <!-- Artifact to deploy is assembled zip file. -->
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
              <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
              <version>${project.version}</version>
              <packaging>zip</packaging>
              <file>target/${project.build.finalName}-bin.zip</file>
              <url>${project.distributionManagement.repository.url}</url>
              <updateReleaseInfo>true</updateReleaseInfo>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>

          <!-- Configure for release environment. -->
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <descriptors>
                <descriptor>src/main/assembly/dist-rel.xml</descriptor>
              </descriptors>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>

        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>

  </profiles>
```

Comment: Is that really the easiest (or canonical) way to choose between test.properties, dev.properties, etc?

Comment: That's how we do it at least. It has been working great for us and it is not hard to maintain, it was just hard to figure it out the first time.